Why is this Baxandall audio gain control circuit stable?
In the article "Audio gain controls (part 2)" in Wireless World, November, 1980, pages 79-83, Peter Baxandall presents the design of a stereo volume control circuit based on linear dual-ganged pots that is tolerant of mismatches in the resistance of the two pots, and has a nearly logarithmic transfer function as the pot is turned.
These are inverting opamp circuits with gain < 1 over a significant portion of the pot sweep, and I don't understand why they are stable.  His starting point is 
(Fig. 22 a., page 80), with transfer function \$\frac{-k'}{1-k'+R_1/R}\$.
With a non-ideal op amp typically compensated only down to a gain of 1, I would think this circuit would be unstable whenever \$k'\$ is sufficiently small, but that's not his final circuit, because he wants to get rid of the dependence on the pot resistance \$R\$.
After some clever manipulation he comes up with Fig. 23 b, with a unity buffer that gives high impedance to the output of the pot, and an inverting op amp with a gain of about -8, and a transfer function \$\frac{-k'}{1-k'+1/8}\$ which has no dependence on the accuracy of Rpot, just the ratio between Ra and Rb.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Is this stable?  Circuit lab gives the following Bode plot for the open loop.  Is the trick here that the phase shifts for the buffer are cancelling the phase shifts for the inverting amp?  I don't get how to evaluate this when \$k'\$ gets very close to 0, so that closed loop gain is << 0dB.



I'm heading off to sleep, but if k'=0 then opamp A is a follower and can be removed leaving Ra and Rb in parallel so opamp B is also a follower whose output follows the (+) input at ground -- no output. Let me know if I'm not seeing right. (I didn't look at the charts since this device has a tiny screen.)

Noise gain, not signal gain, is relevant for assessing op-amp stability. Using that search term you find many sources explaining it, such as this Analog Devices tutorial: https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-033.pdf


These are inverting opamp circuits with gain < 1 over a significant
portion of the pot sweep, and I don't understand why they are stable.

It's the op-amp feedback factor that is all important for judging stability. Both inverting and non-inverting op-amp configurations have the same feedback factor and that is: -
$$FF = \dfrac{R_g}{R_g+R_f}$$
Where \$R_f\$ is the resistor from output to inverting input and, \$R_g\$ is the resistor to ground (in the case of a non-inverting amplifier) or the resistor that connects the input to the inverting amplifier.
Feedback factor (FF) is the same in both cases and, when \$R_g\$ becomes much larger than \$R_f\$, FF becomes unity.
Hence you treat the stability of a very-low-gain inverting op-amp circuit exactly as you would when analysing a unity gain non-inverting amplifier: -

Image from Electronics tutorials

Thank you!  You perfectly summed up my incorrect assumption!  My misunderstanding was, I think, based on this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/156104/21822 to a question about attenuators.  In retrospect I have found this question which describes exactly the mistake I was making: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/544404/21822

At the circuit zero gain point (k'=0) the op amp's (-) input is connected to the output, giving a gain-of-one follower configuration, which is stable for any unity-gain stabilized op amp.

Feedback loops are stable if the gain is less than 1 and the phase is greater than -180deg. The gain at the -180deg point is much less than one.
At it looks stable
